# Trouble to compile QT app with webkitwidgets on Ubuntu10.04

Tags: qt

I have developed QT application with C++ on Ubuntu10.04.
Now I am developing an app with **QWebPage** and **QWebFrame**.
When I compile my project, following error is shown.

```
/home/linden/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle'
/home/linden/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `gst_query_parse_nth_buffering_range'
/home/linden/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `gst_element_link_pads_full'
/home/linden/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `gst_is_initialized'
/home/linden/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `gst_query_get_n_buffering_ranges'
```

I think this error is occurred for **webkitwidgts**.
Do you have an idea to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: libgstreamer and libgstreamer-dev are installed on your system? When they have been installed, "-lgstreamer-\*.\*" is put on linking command line?

Comment: Thanks!   I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install all dependences before installing qt creator, also did you add QT +=webkitwidgets to your .pro file ? And i really recommend you to upgrade your ubuntu to 15.04

Comment: Thanks! I have already added QT += webkitwidgets. But I don't install dependences. Please tell me what I should install.

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu go to link abovs and scroll down . There are two commends which might help you. If i helped you please accept my answer and vote it up

Comment: But i really recommend you updating your OS . it is possible that QT reguires some files which are not available on your 10.04 so all you should do is        1 .  upgrade ubuntu.    2 install dependences 3 install one more time qt creator 4 qt+=webkitwidgets .If I 'm wrong and only my previous hint helped you you probably got dependences installed.